# Unity: Flip Sprite Direction

Tags: unity, sprites

I'm toying around with the new Sprite class in Unity, and I'm trying to work out how to change the direction the sprite is facing ("flip" it). I'm sure I can most likely just scale it across the x axis by -1, but I'd just like to know if there's a new, "official" way of doing it with Sprite or SpriteRenderer. Thanks!

Comment: flip the texture

Comment: Note that simple flipping leads to [ambidextrous sprites](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbidextrousSprite), which may or may not be appropriate for the game you're making. If you want to avoid that, you'll either need a perfectly symmetric sprite, or a seperate (set of) sprites for the reverse direction.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the "official" way is to just invert the scale across the x axis. (That's how it's done in the 2D project example, so I think it's safe to assume there's no fancier way of doing it.)

Answer (score 4):

You should aim to keep the scale of your "containers" like the root of the character at (1,1,1). So I recommend having the sprite as a child of the gameobject, you don't want changing the scale of the sprite affecting the collider for example. Then flip the scale of that child.

Comment: I second this, when scaling the x your rotations will reverse as well.  If you want to flip the sprite and save yourself a lot of headache, make it a child and scale the child's x to -1.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you can flip the x value of the local scale:

```
var direction = 1; //  or -1, depending which way you want the sprite pointing.

// Sets the local scale of the current GameObject
transform.localScale = new Vector3(direction, 1, 1);
```

(Try flipping the y value too!)

Comment: You're right. Two others have already said. Why answer with the same thing again?

Comment: No one had any code samples, I figured it would be nice to have one.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Unity 4.3 - 2D Game Walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qE8cuHI93c) at [about 8:15](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qE8cuHI93c#t=495), their implementation of the Flip() function to reverse the character sets the x scale to -1